# how to read the returned values from running a powershell script

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, powershell, asp.net-mvc-5

I am work on an asp.net mvc web application and i am calling powershell scripts inside my web application, as follow:-

```
var shell = PowerShell.Create();

string PsCmd = "add-pssnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core; $vCenterServer = '" + vCenterName + "';$vCenterAdmin = '" + vCenterUsername + "' ;$vCenterPassword = '" + vCenterPassword + "';" + System.Environment.NewLine;

PsCmd = PsCmd + "$VIServer = Connect-VIServer -Server $vCenterServer -User $vCenterAdmin -Password $vCenterPassword;" + System.Environment.NewLine;

PsCmd = PsCmd + "Get-VMHost " + System.Environment.NewLine;  

shell.Commands.AddScript(PsCmd);

var results = shell.Invoke();
```

now I will get the following values :-

[image]

so can anyone adivce how i can access values such as Build, or loop thorugh thr NetworkInfo ? thanks
**EDIT**
full trace picture:-
[image]

Comment: Isn't `Build` there for you to use?

Comment: @CliveDM i mean how i can access it as i usually deal with strongly typed objects where i write something such as modelobkect.buiild;..

Comment: Uhh, that you can use `dynamic` keyword.

Comment: can yuo adivce more please

Comment: I composed an answer, please have a try.

Comment: @CliveDM did not work i got the following error 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<System.Management.Automation.PSObject>' does not contain a definition for 'Build'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dynamic` keyword, you wouldn't have to know the strong type of one object. In fact, without having to know the type in advance, you can use this as you expected: **a variable can be anything**.

For example, I could declare a method like this:

```
    static void DynamicTest(dynamic arg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(arg.aaa);
    }
```

`DynamicTest` accessed `aaa` field(or property) in `arg` without knowing that whether `arg` itself has `aaa` or not. Using a `dynamic` means that you don't want compiler to detect the possible errors that you may or may not access something from a variable that does not actually have it.

You can call this method with:

```
DynamicTest(new {aaa = "I am accessible"});
```

it'll run, also you can call this method with:

```
DynamicTest(1); // I will cause runtime exception
```

So, in your specific situation, you could define  the variable `result` as dynamic since you now know that you'll get a variable that contains several properties that you want to use.

```
var res = shell.Invoke()[0];
dynamic obj = res.BaseObject;
```

Therefore you can use it like a regular variable(without IntelliSense of course).

```
Console.WriteLine(obj.Build); // Now I can compile yay!
```

Here.

Comment: but when i try the following "results.Build" i got the following error 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<System.Management.Automation.PSObject>' does not contain a definition for 'Build'

Comment: @johnG Well, this `result` seem to be a `collection`, set a breakpoint on it and inspect what does it have. The picture doesn't seem to be the root, try post the actual tree structure here.

Comment: it is under a [0] then i got Base

Comment: @johnG, Yep, I edited my answer, have a try then ;-)